# How can i use MenuItem in TextBox data template in WPF?

Tags: wpf, binding, datatemplate

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="RowItem" x:Name="RowItem"> 
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Content}">
    <TextBox.ContextMenu>
      <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header="Browse" Click="MenuItem_Click" />
      </ContextMenu>
    </TextBox.ContextMenu>
  </TextBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

Now, all I need is: after browsing, I should get the selected file to be shown in this text box, but since its in a data template, I can't set the `Text` of the textbox because it has no id.

Note that I fill this data template at the code side with data rows.

Can anyone please help me? I have spent days on this problem.

Comment: You should modify the binding source of `TextBox.Text`, not the `TextBox` directly.

Comment: can you please explain more?

Comment: You are binding `TextBox.Text` to a `Content` property. To change the displayed text, change the value of this property.

Comment: You should be able to access it from your event handler using the `DataContext` of the sender object (which is the `MenuItem`).

Comment: actually its not a property but its a column name since this data template is like a repeater so its filled dynamically with data rows and its basic structure is   DataColumn column;
column = new DataColumn();
            column.DataType = typeof(string);
            column.ColumnName = "Content";
            dataTemplateSource.Columns.Add(column);

Comment: Please add more context in order to help to understand what you are doing. It's not clear how this template is used. If you want to change the column name you have to set the header of the unknown view component that owns this column. Please add more details!